# How do I fix PhoneGap build errors? "Exception in InvokeScriptCallback"

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am trying to build a PhoneGap-based Wondows Phone 7 application, but I keep getting the following two errors:

```
 GapBrowser_Navigated :: /app/www/page2.html
    Der Thread '<Kein Name>' (0x16660ac6) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
    Der Thread '<Kein Name>' (0x16000752) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
    "UI Task" (Verwaltet): "System.SR.dll" geladen
    Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.ArgumentException" ist in mscorlib.dll aufgetreten.
    Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.SystemException" ist in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll aufgetreten.
    ERROR: Exception in InvokeScriptCallback :: An unknown error has occurred. Error: 800A1393.
    INFO: AppDeactivated
    Der Thread '<Kein Name>' (0x126a0b7a) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
    Der Thread '<Kein Name>' (0x177306ea) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
```

Comment: are you using version 2.0.0?

Comment: then maybe try to upgrade to 2.3.0, which is the newest one - if the problem persists, you can try and file a bug request at the [Cordova JIRA bug tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=)

Comment: can you print the logs in english?

Comment: Thank you for that information, i hava error in my javascript